# CU4 - Now Power View won't work

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

After installing Comulative Update 4 for SQL Server SP1 on my System i am encountering the following error Message when i try to edit or create new, Power View Reports

**Original Message** (Includes German)

```
System.NullReferenceException: [Arg_NullReferenceException]
Argumente: 
Debuggingressourcen-

Zeichenfolgen sind nicht verfügbar. Oft enthalten der Schlüssel und die Argumente genügend Informationen zur Diagnose des Problems.

 Weitere Informationen erhalten Sie unter http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=5.1.30214.00&File=mscorlib.dll&Key=Arg_NullReferenceException


   bei Microsoft.Reporting.AdHoc.Shell.Regions.FieldList.Internal.FieldListControl.TreeView_LostFocus(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)


   bei MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(UInt32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)


   bei MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName, UInt32 flags)
```

**Translated Message**

```
System.NullReferenceException: [Arg_NullReferenceException]
Arguments: 
Debuggingressources-

Strings are not Available. Often the Keys Contain enaugh information and the Arguments enaugh Information to Diagnose the Problem.

 More Information on: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=5.1.30214.00&File=mscorlib.dll&Key=Arg_NullReferenceException


   at Microsoft.Reporting.AdHoc.Shell.Regions.FieldList.Internal.FieldListControl.TreeView_LostFocus(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)


   at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(UInt32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)


   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName, UInt32 flags)
```

I have Tried and had this same issue Happening with CU9 as well.

I checked if the Reporting Services were on, they were
The Power View Feature for the Site was activated and everything else i know of as well.

Is there something i Need to do after installing a Comulative Update ?

Thanks a lot for your help, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem deleting the temp files on internet explorer in the client computer, because the power view viewer is a silverlight application and must be updated with the CU

Answer (score -1):

I deleted the temp files of IE and it worked! :D